# copyright question

Tags: copyright, program, software

hello all sound designers!

I have a question about the sound material that comes with a program like Logic Studio Pro 9. It has tons of sounds and parts of music in there. Can i use them on my projects? Commercial of course! and yes i own the program its not pirated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yip you can :-)

Comment: thnx for the quick answer Andrew

Comment: Ah I always wondered that one :)

Comment: You can find the official paperwork for it here: http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/logicstudio8.pdf (a long version of yes...)